# Calling method on page load

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following method saved in my controller that automatically deletes items based on a preset time limit (i.e. anything created over a week ago).

```
def auto_del
    Item.where("created_at <= ?", Time.now - 7.days).destroy_all
end
```

Where is the best place to call this method and how would I call it on the item.html.erb page load?

I tried calling it in a `before_action` in the Application Controller and in the specific item Controller, no luck.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think `delete_all` instead of `destroy_all` will be incredibly faster.

Comment: `Destroy_all` is more better compare to `delete_all` as it delete associated records as well.

Comment: Put it in a cron job. Say, will right every night.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a cron job hit an endpoint on your application is not ideal. Thats not really what your endpoints are for! Check out the [clockwork](https://github.com/tomykaira/clockwork) gem. It lets you schedule tasks from within your application.

Answer (score 1):

You have two place to do.

1. Call this method inside the `Item Controller` `index` method.
2. Make a cron job for this which will schedule to run daily on specific time.

Ex.- Consider sidekiq delaying job, for something like [sidekiq](http://sidekiq.org)

It is useless to call this in before action because it will call before every action which is senseless as it will delete week record in 1 first attempt.